# which name is better?

Tags: traditional-characters

which name is better?
for a girl

which one is better in pronunciation and meaning?
I want to use it as my Chinese name

Answer (score 1):

琉璟 and 留镜, you could say the pronunciation is almost the same, though 璟 is in 3rd tone whilst 镜 is in 4th tone. Personally, I would prefer 琉璟 b/c it gives people some sense of Chinese culture, and moreover, it reads more poetic and antique. You may impress Chinese people with 琉璟 rather than just 留镜.

You could also know more detailed meaning of these characters if you look them both up in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not a native speaker, my opinion may not be very helpful. But the first one seems ok to me as a girl's personal name (名子). The second one, less so.

There is a website ([name.renren.com](http://name.renren.com/)) where you can search to see if other people have a given full name (姓名).  However it's a bit slow/impractical. It didn't have any entries for 李琉璟 or 王琉璟 (李 and 王 are common family names).

I suppose you don't need to decide on a family name (姓) straight away.

Answer (score 1):

If Liu is your last name, I suggest "劉靜", "劉晶" for female, and  "劉景", "劉京", "劉敬" for male. I prefer a name that is easy to write.

琉璟 is more 詩情畫意, 留镜 is quite distinct, both can be a good pen name. If you like them very much, you can consider naming yourself as,

劉 X, "字"琉璟(留镜). In which X is any word mentioned in the suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

Neither 琉璟  nor 留鏡 is a typical woman name

liu2 characters:

> 流: flow; drift; circulate; current; class; fake

> 榴: pomegranate

> 留: remain; keep

> 瘤: tumour

> 硫: sulphur

> 餾: distil; heat up

> 騮: red horse

> 劉: a Chinese surname

> 琉: coloured glaze

> 瀏: clear; transparent

> 飂: wind in high places

~

Jing4 Characters:

> 靚: beautiful; pretty; nice; teenager

> 淨: clean; pure; net; cleanse; always

> 靜: still; calm; silent; quiet; serene; composed

> 凈: clean; pure; net; completely

> 勁: strong; strength; extremely

> 竟: finish; throughout; unexpectedly

> 競: compete; vie

> 瀞: pool in a river

> 敬: respect; honour; esteem

> 境: boundary; frontier; region

> 徑: footpath; diameter; means

> 鏡: mirror; lens

> 痙: convulsions; spasm

> 靖: tranquil; pacify

> 婧: slender (of woman); delicate; virtuous

- If Liu jing is the first name, only 琉靜, 琉瀞, 琉婧, 流靜, 流瀞, 流婧 should be considered
- If Liu is the family name, jing is the first name, then your choices would be 劉靜, 劉瀞, or 劉婧

(靚 is a female name, but too old fashion)